# Android Layout Below and Above

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I got three TextViews. The first and the third are defined with a not changing Text. The second, the TextView between the first and the third gets the value with an input. How can I set the second TextView between the first and the third in the layout?

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondtext"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/firsttext"
android:layout_above="@+id/thirdtext"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firsttext"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thirdtext"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

That doesn't work!

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondtext"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firsttext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firsttext"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="4"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

That also doesn't work

Comment: to get input you need edittext box. and if you want then vertically then set orientation of linear layout as vertical and if horizontal then orientation as horizontal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too many dependencies, check if you are getting any circular dependency error in xml. As per your requirement, without specifying the spacing and other UI details, a solution:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firsttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="first"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firsttext"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="second"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/secondtext"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="third"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But if my second text is too long, the thirdtext is no longer on display.. because the second Text is not defined..

Comment: if you mean second text being multiline and pushing the third text away, specify ellipsize and single line or lines in the textview or just in the second textview.

Comment: can't understand your requirement clearly, can you post what is the output now for your code above and what/how do you want it to be

Comment: I did what you said and it looks like what I want, but my App chrashes.

Comment: post that logcat, check for different names of resources.

Comment: post the whole layout,code - log cat for checking where the app crashes

Comment: thank you. your example was totally right. the app crashed because of a code mistake.

Comment: good it helped you, accepted answer, thats enough, and with the name like that, you can avoid saying thankyou, explicitly

Comment: ohh I'm very sorry for that :( but thank you for the answer thankyou thanks you :) thank you. #thankyou

Comment: I know this is mildly irrelevant but shouldn't the text be set in the strings file? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/thirdText"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstText"
```

Make sure to add your left and right TextView first with the fixed width and

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But try this..
If you are using Relative layout as parent then

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondtext"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/firsttext"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

to show three textviews in horizontal way.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondtext"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/firsttext"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

to show in vertical way..

Comment: But if my second text is too long, the thirdtext is no longer on display.. because the second Text is not defined..

Comment: no vertical but the second Text (the text in the middle) is not defined and if it's too long the third text will be out of screen

Comment: This is common problem. To avoid this, set following attribute to some value android:layout_width="100dp" //value is your wish.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `LinearLayout` with `height="wrap_content"` and `width="fill_parent"`.

You can overcome your problem with two ways. Either add `android:layout_below="@id/TextViewExample"` in your *Textviews* or use `android:layout_marginTop="10dip"`

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firsttext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="first"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/firsttext"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="second"
            android:layout_below="@id/firstText"
             android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thirdtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/secondtext"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="third"
             android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:layout_below="@id/secondtext"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`width="fill_parent"` - This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by `match_parent`.